# How do I say that one thing is another using active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, be, active-voice, hypercorrection

I've tried typing this question or variations of this question into Google to no avail, so I apologize if it has already been answered elsewhere. I'm trying to edit a paper for a class in which the instructor has written the following:

> I know that [to be verbs] CAN have the proper place, so don't think me a tyrant. But since one of the major goals of this class is to get your [sic] to write at this high level, I want you to strive to write without any use of the TO BE verb in your independent clauses.

In this particular case, the entire sentence is "The American man is a proud man."  Perhaps not the greatest sentence, but it is setting up a point later in the paragraph.  The *only* verb in the entire sentence is "is," and I feel like, even though it is technically a to-be verb, it is not being used as an auxiliary or helping verb and, thus, must be active?  The man is actively *being* proud.

The sentence could be somewhat rewritten as "The American man exists in a perpetual state of proudness," etc., but, aside from somewhat altering the meaning that the author is trying to get across, it feels a lot like wordiness for wordiness's sake.

Is it best to simply eliminate the sentence altogether in this context, or can anyone think of a way to reword this and make it "active voice" (which, to the professor, apparently just means no to-be verbs) without completely losing the meaning/clarity?

Comment: Proudness defines the American man.    But really,  I still want a ’to be’ verb to qualify it:  “Proudness is one of the characteristics that defines the American man.

Comment: The American takes pride in himself and his country.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[E-Prime, or English-Prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-Prime), constitutes an exercise in writing/speaking English without using any form of the verb "to be". For instance, in place of saying "The American man *is* proud," one might write "The American man *feels* proud," or "The American man *tends to stay* proud," or as Xanne above says, "*takes* pride", all active verbs.